# Time sum of similar employees in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in my database.

First table is `Employee`:

[image]

Second table is `EmployeeTimeIn` : (HoursConsumed have time in seconds!)

[image]

Third table is `EmployeeTimeOut`:

[image]

I wrote the following SQL query which lists all the employees grouped by their IDs and working time of each time in session:

```
select 
    v.EID, e.EmployeeName, v.Time_In, v.Time_Out,
    convert(varchar(5), SUM(v.HoursConsumed) / 3600)  + ':' + 
    convert(varchar(5), SUM(v.HoursConsumed) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + 
    convert(varchar(5), (SUM(v.HoursConsumed) % 60)) as workingtime,
    v.Date_Ref
from
    (select 
         e1.EID, e1.Time_In, e2.Time_Out, e1.HoursConsumed,    
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e1.Date_Ref, 111) as Date_Ref
     from EmployeeTimeIn as e1, EmployeeTimeOut as e2
     where e1.Refid = e2.Refid) as v, Employee as e
     where v.EID = e.EmployeeID
     group by 
          v.EID, e.EmployeeName, v.Time_In, v.Time_Out, v.HoursConsumed, v.Date_Ref;
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

I need to modify this query so that for each employee it shows the grand total working time in `workingtime` column. In this scenario It will display `workingtime` of 0:41:53 for EID 4 and 0:0:39 for EID 200.

Please advise.

*(NOTE: final output should have three rows for this example data because i need to show Time In and Time Out fields in final table too!)*

Comment: Please use explicit JOINs rather than "table, table" syntax.

Comment: Hi @Nida Sulheri i am facing the same problem . Can you please provide me the table structure or you use same , i need to implement the same logic in my project . Regards

Comment: @A.Goutam Tables structures are mentioned in my above post... Please refer to tables screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you always can convert WorkingTimeInSeconds to hours:

```
;WITH Totals(WorkingTimeInSeconds, EmployeeId, EmployeeName, DateRef) AS
(
   SELECT 
      e.EmployeeId,
      e.EmployeeName,
      eti.Date_Refб
      SUM(HoursConsumed) WorkingTimeInSeconds,
    FROM Employee e
    JOIN EmployeeTimeIn eti
      ON e.EmployeeId = eti.EId
    GROUP BY 
      e.EmployeeId,
      e.EmployeeName,
      eti.Date_Ref
)

SELECT
  Totals.EmployeeId,
  Totals.EmployeeName,
  eti.Time_In,
  eto.Time_Out,
  eti.Ref_Date,
  eti.WorkingTimeInSeconds
FROM Totals
JOIN EmployeeTimeIn eti
  ON Totals.DateRef = eti.Date_Ref AND eti.EID=Totals.EmployeeId
JOIN EmployeeTimeOut eto
  ON Totals.DateRef = eto.Date_Ref AND eto.EID=Totals.EmployeeId AND eti.RefId = eto.RefId
```

Comment: This query works but it shows two rows only. Can you please read the NOTE in my post which i just added!!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. SQL Server shows error at some points in your provided query. Please download the DB from here and see what you can do to fix it...
http://www.mediafire.com/?ia0ljcvg99200vp

Comment: It worked like charm, you are the real DB champion :)
Can you make a small modification in it. First is I want similiar employees group together and secondly I need to show this table in following columns order: EmployeeID,Name,Timein,TimeOut,Date,TotalWorkingtime. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @NidaSulheri Corrected the columns order. What is "Employee group"?

Answer (score 0):

You could treat your current query results as a fourth table, and then do a select sum from that.  Of course you would need to keep the values of your original query in numeric values, but I'm not sure what hours consumed represents.

```
select EmployeeName, sum(workingtime), date_ref
from (
-- original query but modified to not convert strings
select     v.EID,e.EmployeeName,v.Time_In,v.Time_Out,convert(varchar(5),SUM(v.HoursConsumed)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),SUM(v.HoursConsumed)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(SUM(v.HoursConsumed)%60)) as workingtime,v.Date_Ref
from   ...
) group by EmployeeName, date_ref
```

You could also pull the time calculation out into a function to get hours by employee and date, but not sure about your data.  Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, HoursConsumed have time in seconds. Can you please paste complete query because i did not understand what you mean by "-- original query but modified to not convert strings"... thanks

Comment: Please refer to the NOTE in my post which i just added!